# VBA collection member property

Tags: class, vba

I have created a class with couple of fields and one property.
Next I created a collection of instances of that class and made the entire collection public.
I am trying to access a property of an class instance inside of collection.
So far no results.
 My question is: Can I access a property of an instance of a class which is a member of a collection ?

Comment: Could you post a sample of your code, and the specifics of the "No Results", i.e. an error, or just `Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes, you can.

`myCollection [i].Propertyname`

Where i = the position of a class object in the collection

Not 100% sure what it is in VBA syntax bit it should be similar.